# Can I scale a background using CSS3?

Tags: css, transform, scale

More specifically, is it possible to scale a tiled background image using CSS3's `transform:scale(x,y)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can't use transform:scale(), if you know the final size of the background image that you need, you can you can use background-size to get the same effect.

```
.selector {
    background-image: url(http://path/to/image.png);
    background-size: 200px 100px;
}
```

However, if you always want to, say, "double" the width of the image that you use as a background, then that doesn't seem to be possible at this time.

**EDIT:** Note that while the background-size style supports % based parameters, it's not as a percentage of the image size, but the size of the window.

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
background-size: 200px;
background-size: 200px 100px;
background-size: 200px 100px, 400px 200px;
background-size: auto 200px;
background-size: 50% 25%;
background-size: contain;
background-size: cover; 

 (or)

img.bg {
    /* Set rules to fill background */
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 1024px;

    /* Set up proportionate scaling */
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;

    /* Set up positioning */
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) { /* Specific to this particular image */
    img.bg {
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -512px;   /* 50% */
    }
}



       (or)


    #bg {
        position:fixed; 
        top:0; 
        left:0; 

        /* Preserve aspet ratio */
        min-width:100%;
        min-height:100%;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not good in CSS. But just the idea: create background div with tiled background (using z-index) and scale it. It should work

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can scale it but try using percentage.

```
background-size: 100%;
```

But you need to consider the different resolutions of a screen. 4:3  4:9 etc.

I would recommend you to use this jQuery script. [jQuery Strech Background](http://www.ajaxblender.com/bgstretcher-jquery-stretch-background-plugin.html)